# How to create a custom render extension in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, render

Please let me know that how can I create a custom render extension in SSRS 2008. I have created it in SSRS 2005, but when I try using the same code in SQL Server 2008, it does not work.
The `IRenderingExtension` interface does not seem to be compatible with 2008.

It gives the following compilation error:

> Class 'Renderer' must implement 'Function Render(report As Report,
>   reportServerParameters As
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, deviceInfo As
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, clientCapabilities
>   As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, ByRef
>   renderProperties As System.Collections.Hashtable,
>   createAndRegisterStream As Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream) As
>   Boolean' for interface
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.IRenderingExtension'.

Please help..........

Answer (score 0):

The name space for `IRenderingExtension` has changed from `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering` (2005)
to 
`Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering` in 2008.